# displaying sql data in html table rows dinamically using ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, html

I want to do what the title says, because the sql database is too slow, I have a table with some values and I would like to display them one per one, while the rest is loading, but my main problem I'm creating one table and then I insert ten values in that table, then I create the second table and insert the other ten values... and so on. But If I want to insert a row in the first table, I don't know if that's posible, I've been googling and didn't found a way to do that.

```
//OFFER ID
echo "<table class='calendar_table' align=left style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<th>OFFER ID</th></tr>";
$query = "SELECT installs.advertiser_id FROM installs WHERE YEAR(installs.time_of_install) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(installs.time_of_install) = MONTH(NOW()) GROUP BY installs.advertiser_id LIMIT 10";
$result_offerId = $conn->query($query);
$offerId= array();
if ($result_offerId->num_rows > 0)
{
    foreach($result_offerId as $row) {
        if($row['advertiser_id'] == 0)continue;
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['advertiser_id']."</td><td>";
        $offerId[] = $row['advertiser_id'];
    }
}
else
{
    echo "0 results";die();
}
echo "</table>";


//OFFER NAME
echo "<table align=left style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<th>OFFER NAME</th></tr>";
```

As you can see, I close the fist table and open the second, and then I'm not able to reinsert rows in the first table. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: adding to table followed by ajax response??

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#submit).click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'get_table_data.php',
                success: function(data) {               
                   $('.calendar_table').html(data);

                }
            });


   });
```

use your controller file in url.after submit you can see that table data will be loaded.

Comment: please add table tag in previous file

Answer (score 0):

Have your PHP file output a table row instead of a table. Then when you do your ajax request, you can append the `<tr>` to the same table, and repeat the process as many times as possible.